# A method can only be hooked once per class hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, aspect

When I use Aspects, I hook a method in a superClass, then I hook the method in a subClass, I get "A method can only be hooked once per class hierarchy". why I can't hook both them? Thank!

Comment: "It allows you to add code to existing methods per class or per instance". when you hook it into a superClass to fit in some code on a method all of its inherited subclasses should have this method available as in the superclass. Aka no need to hook it again in subclass

Comment: ps: you should probably point out that you possibly meant [steipete/Aspects](https://github.com/steipete/Aspects)

Comment: OK! I will study, thanks

Comment: I've studied it. I already know the principle！

Comment: Not sure about the result you want, show your code